# Where can I find a reliable database of civilian ATS Routes?

Tags: flight-planning

I am looking for an updated source of ATS routes. Are there any free and reliable (ie produced by the FAA or Eurocontrol) datasets available?

Comment: Ideally I am looking for a dataset that I can readily import in a database (for example a csv dataset).

Comment: Does not exist.

Comment: OK. So how do airlines proceed? Do they build there own ATS Route database?

Comment: @BigONotation The data is licensed or sub-licensed from a provider such as Jeppesen, LH Systems Lido, or NAVBLUE.

Comment: Thanks. Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it